# how to specify format of timestamp while creating table in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, psql

I have created table with query:

```
CREATE TABLE Z (
A varchar(30),
B varchar(30),
C timestamp,
D numeric,
E varchar(30),
F varchar(30),
G varchar(30),
H numeric
);
```

Now, I have a csv file with delimiter '|' and entries in this file are like

```
1313131|131313131|20130103115041|20.0000000|ABCD|EFGH||0.0000000
```

I am trying following command to import the data in the table:

```
\copy Z from filename WITH (FORMAT CSV , DELIMITER '|', NULL '');
```

But I am getting following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "20130103115041"
CONTEXT:  COPY Z, line 1, column C: "20130103115041"
```

I guess I have to specify the timestamp format while creating table so that it can accept the input in "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert such a timestamp with:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('20130103115041','YYYYMMDDHHMISS');
```

However, `COPY` doesn't offer input filters. So you'll probably want to `CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE ...` to store the `COPY` data, then do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` to insert and transform the data.

Comment: And any implicit or explicit casts from `timestamp with time zone` to `timestamp` would drop the session's current time zone from the `timestampz` without butchering anything, right? Time zones and DST have triggered many extended swearing sessions over the years so I'm always paranoid about them.

Comment: @muistooshort If in doubt, `SET TimeZone = 'UTC'` first. Similarly, plenty of swearing. I always have to look the rules up as I can't ever remember off the top of my head, so unsure.