# Import data with timestamps from mongodb to postgresql via csv

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, csv, pgadmin

My goal is to move my data from mongodb to postgresql 9.1.13.
I used `mongoexport` to export my collections from mongodb to csv files. Later I was creating tables with pgAdmin 1.18.1 and importing from csv files using pgAdmin's [import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUYup.png).

It worked fine till I reached the csv with datetime fields. In csv file the column (called "start" in my case) has the following format `2014-02-04T19:50:35Z`. The format I have set for the corresponding column in pgAdmin is `timestamp without time zone` (I have tried also `timestamp with time zone`). What I get from pgAdmin is:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "start"
CONTEXT:  COPY context, line 1, column start_time: "start"
```

My question is: shall I export from mongodb somehow differently or shall I alter the column type in pgAdmin?

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012128/how-to-specify-format-of-timestamp-while-creating-table-in-postgresql), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042452/importing-csv-with-timestamp-column-dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss-using-psql-copy) solutions, but not sure what is a good way to go, because I am going to have more imports from mongodb and want to use the most standard, universal timestamps format and avoid defining custom datetime formats.

P.S. I am a noob in SQL and postgres.

Comment: That's really odd, `2014-02-04T19:50:35Z` is accepted by PostgreSQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2546 -- it seems, import may want to parse a `'start'` string as a timestamp. Did you checked the *Header* checkbox at *Misc. options*?

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaah, thanks @pozs! that was the Header checkbox at Misc. options. After checking it, it worked... my first day with postgres...

Answer the question, so I can mark it as solved

Comment: then you should check your already imported tables too, they may contain header rows.

Comment: yupp, that was the case...
 merci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the the *Header* checkbox at *Misc. options*, if your `csv`s contains headers.

You should check your already imported tables too, they may contain header rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HEADER` option to the copy command to make it ignore the first line

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

[image]